# Bokeh button callback failing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am doing some data analysis in a Jupyter notebook that uses Bokeh widgets to help with interactivity. One of my widgets is a button, and whenever I click the button, the callback function does not run.

I was able to successfully do this in another Jupyter notebook, so I am unsure why it is not working in the one I am working on now. To try and isolate the button from the other widgets, I wrote the following simplified code:

```py
def test():
    s = Button(label = 'test')
    def clicked():
        print('clicked')

    def modify_doc(doc):
        doc.title = 'testing'
        doc.add_root(row(s))
        s.on_click(clicked)
        #fileDrop.on_change('value', update_file)


    url = list(notebookapp.list_running_servers())
    url = str(url[0].get('port'))
    handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
    app = Application(handler)
    show(app, notebook_url = 'http://localhost:%s' % (url))
test()
```

With this code, I can get the button to display correctly, but the callback function still does not run whenever I click it.

EDIT: I found out what the issue was - I needed to swap the order of the doc.add_root and s.on_click lines. I am still unsure why this is though, so if anyone could shed some light on this, it'd be appreciated!